# Algorithm books on a range of topics

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, data-structures, books

I've been tasked with building a library of books on algorithms for our small company (about 15 people). The budget is more than 5k, but certainly less than 10k, so I can buy a fair number of books. All people here have at least a Bachelor's degree in CS or a closely related field, so while I will get some basic textbook like Cormen, I'm more interested in good books on advanced topics. (I will get Knuth's 4 volumes, BTW.)

Some list of topics would be:

- Sorting algorithms
- Graph algorithms
- String algorithms
- Randomized algorithms
- Distributed algorithms
- Combinatorial algorithms
- etc.

Essentially I'm looking for good recommendations on books about major topics within CS related to algorithms and data structures. Especially stuff that goes beyond what's typically covered in algorithm and data structure classes as part of a Bachelor's degree at a good school. I know the question is quite fuzzy, since I'm looking for generically useful material. The software we develop is mostly system level stuff handling large amounts of data.

The ideal would also be to find anything that would cover fairly recent cool data structures and algorithms, which most people might not have heard about.

---

EDIT: Here are some preliminary books that I think I should get:

- Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al.
- Algorithm Design by Kleinberg, Tardos
- The Art of Computer Programming Vol 1-4 by Knuth
- Approximation Algorithms by Vazirani
- The Design of Approximation Algorithms by Williamson, Shmoys
- Randomized Algorithms by Motwani, Raghavan
- Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Sipser
- Computational Complexity by Arora, Barak
- Computers and Intractability by Garey and Johnson
- Combinatorial Optimization by Schrijver

A few other books my colleagues wanted that deal with techniques and algorithms for language design, compilers and formal methods are:

- Types and Programming Languages by Pierce
- Principles of Model Checking by Baier, Katoen
- Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools by Aho, Lam, Sethi, Ullman
- The Compiler Design Handbook: Optimizations and Machine Code Generation, Second Edition by Srikant, Shankar
- The Garbage Collection Handbook: The Art of Automatic Memory Management by Jones, Hosking, Moss

Comment: Books that every library should have: * Algorithm Design by Jon Kleinberg and Éva Tardos * Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Michael Sipser * Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness by M. R. Garey and D. S. Johnson

Comment: > * Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Michael Sipser This is a great book, but it is more about Automata and Languages, Context-Free-Languages, Turing Machines, Complexity Theory and so on. It is not much about Algorithms

Comment: Wow, this is a broad question. How do you expect to verify the quality and coverage of the selection? What is *your* background? What does your company work on? Do you have people with master degrees or doctorates?

Comment: Moderator notice: please do not post single-book answers, and please explain why you're making these choices. There's a $5k budget here: explain how you would spend it! Tell us which books you think are must-have, which topics should be explored further, how you make your selection...

Comment: Are you mainly interested in design, or also in analysis of algorithms? If so, do you want your people to get competent in theoretical analysis, or would you rather they were proficient in more practical means of evaluating efficiency?

Comment: @Raphael I myself have a MSc while we also have a few people with PhDs. The books can certainly be heavy on theory. I'm not looking for something silly like "Algorithms in C++ for SMT solvers", since I know they don't exist. Every advanced book I know is heavy on math and expect the reader to be able to implement the material if needed.

Comment: Any interesting books on implementing modern file systems and database systems? What about data mining and machine learning?

Comment: Regarding your second comment: that is beyond the scope of algorithms books. Regarding your edit: Recent material is unlikely to be covered in established books. Some of the books you list are not about algorithms per se; is your actual target scope wider?

Comment: @Raphael I would beg to differ in the sense that advanced books on algorithms are going to be domain specific. Most compiler books are essentially books on parsing algorithms etc. Similarly, a book on model checking will spend a lot of time covering different ideas for pruning large search spaces.

Comment: @mtf: You are arguing for reading your question even broad than it is. Broad questions are a problem on this platform; you should rather alot your budget to topics that are of import to your company and *focus* the question.

Comment: @mtf: I think you should also consider algorithmic book in data mining ans machine learning. You could consider [Encyclopedia of Algorithms][1] book, which contains all the areas you mentioned!


  [1]: http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-0-387-30770-1

Answer (score 18):

I have not (nearly) read enough books to name $5000 worth of them. Therefore, I will suggest some groups of literature you should cover as well as point you towards selected representatives. I can not claim to have read most of the books in full myself, so I have to rely mostly on descriptions, cursory impression and reputation. I have looked into or worked with most of them to some extent, or had them recommended by experts.

I assume that you want your people to learn what can be done, and how to do it, as opposed to learning what they can't do. In particular, I will leave out books about computability and complexity theory as such; I expect your people to have taken away the relevant messages from their undergraduate education.

- **The Basics**
  Even though your people have learned them at some point, expect them to look
  up the basics. Since sources like Wikipedia are frequently substandard 
  or outright wrong, you want to get them proper reference texts.

  Popular choices include

  - [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) by Cormen, Leiserson et al.
    Very broad introduction that covers many elementary algorithms and data structures as well as basic analysis techniques. A standard text used frequently for teaching purposes and available in its 3rd edition (so most mistakes should have been purged by now). Lots of exercises.
  - [Algorithms](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) by Sedgewick and Wayne
    Another standard text in its fourth edition. Less broad than Cormen, but with more attention to implementation details. Lots of material online, including a [free course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI). Lots of exercises.
  - Introduction to Algorithms -- A Creative Approach by Udi Manber
    Also rather slim a selection of topics, but presented with attention to didactics. The focus is on *inductive* strategies. Contains lots of exercises and solutions (or at least hints) for some. A good secondary reference if you don't like the recommended textbook because of its unusual style.
  - [Concrete Mathematics](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/gkp.html) by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik
    Covers discrete mathematics as relevant to algorithm analysis. Rare in its focus on computer science needs *and* rigor. Very high quality. Lots of exercises with solutions.
- **Analysis of Algorithms**
  In most standard text books, analysis of algorithm usually stops at the level
  of $O$-asymptotics and RAM model. In order to estimate real-world efficiency
  more reliably, it can be necessary to investigate runtime more precisely and
  consider effects like memory hierarchy and communication.

  - [An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/home/) by Sedgewick and Flajolet
    Basic techniques for precise analysis of algorithms. Written by the 
    pioneers of the field. Also has a [free online course](https://www.coursera.org/course/introACpartI).
  - [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp) by Knuth
    *The* reference for high-quality, low-level, precisely analysed 
    algorithms for a whole range of problems. Also serves as reference.
- **Advanced Surveys**

  - [Purely functional data structures](http://books.google.de/books/about/Purely_Functional_Data_Structures.html?id=SxPzSTcTalAC&redir_esc=y) by Okasaki
    Classic and basic literature often focuses on the procedural paradigm. If 
    you want to work in the functional paradigm, new techniques for efficient
    data structures are needed. This book is a detailed overview over the area.
  - [Advanced Data Structures](http://books.google.de/books/about/Advanced_data_structures.html?id=g8rZoSKLbhwC&redir_esc=y) by Brass
    Sometimes, the basic techniques are not enough. This is an overview over
    advanced data structures, with code and many references.
  - [Algorithmics for Hard Problems](http://www.ite.ethz.ch/publications/buch/index_EN) by Hromkovič
    Complexity theory tells us (as practitioners) not to bother looking for
    exact yet efficient algorithms for many natural problems. There are plenty
    of techniques for practically solving these problems; this text shows
    you how.
- **Specialised Literature**

  - [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/) aka The Dragon Book by Aho et al
    Should you ever need to build or tinker with a compiler, this is *the*
    standard text on the area.
  - Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications by Ahuja
    Many problems can be modeled as network  flow problems; this book gives you
    a full coverage of the field.
  - [Probabilistic Graphical Models](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models) by Koller and Friedman
    Graphical models are a major tool in modeling scenarios for machine
    learning (among others) probabilistically. This is a comprehensive overview
    about the complex. There is a related [free online course](https://www.coursera.org/course/pgm).
  - [Handbook of Exact String Matching Algorithms](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/) by Charras and Lecrog
    String matching is an ever important task when dealing with data.
    This book lists most (if not all) relevant algorithms for the job,
    including high-level descriptions as well as implementations.
  - [Analytic Combinatorics](http://ac.cs.princeton.edu/home/) by Sedgewick
    and Flajolet
    The deep mathematical dive after "An Introduction to the Analysis of 
    Algorithms" by the same authors. Not for everybody, but gold for the
    interested.
  - Algorithms on Strings, Trees and Sequences by Gusfield
    Should you ever have to deal with huge amounts of string data (in 
    particular in biology contexts) this is the go-to book as it provides an
    overview over the relevant data structures and algorithms.
- **For the Practitioner**

  - Patterns for Parallel Programming by Mattson et al.
    In practice, you might want to utilise multiple machines to deal with
    large problems. This book is a high-level, example-driven overview 
    over ways to do so, that is how to organise and move data and computing 
    agents. It also addresses ways to implement them with existing tools.
  - [A Guide to Experimental Algorithmics](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item6618711/?site_locale=en_GB) by McGeoch
    When theoretical analysis is too hard or too coarse, you have to perform
    experiments. This is an introduction into how to properly design 
    experiments on algorithms.
  - [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](http://antlr.org/) by Parr
    You often need domain specific languages and tools to parse them. ANTLR is
    a mature and convenient compiler generator, and this is the book best
    suited for learning how to use it. Parr also has some other books on
    DSLs worth checking out.

If you want very recent material, you should consider getting your people access to journals and conference proceedings, maybe by cooperating with a university library. You can also actually let them attend conferences on topics relevant to them resp. your company.

Also, consider asking your people. Have them do their own research (including free samples or copies on the web or libraries) and they will tell you which books they consider relevant to their work. There is no use in buying stuff no one will read.

Comment: And, of course, send them here with their interesting problems. :)

Comment: What about [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://amzn.com/1848000693)?

Comment: @Bartek: Never heard of it, so I can't recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a random collection of books on advanced algorithms based on what I consider as great book about advanced algorithms. Of course this is only my personal opinion and there are many other good books.

- Approximation Algorithms by Vijay V. Vazirani
- The Design of Approximation Algorithms by David P. Williamson, David B. Shmoys
- Computational geometry: an introduction through randomized algorithms by Ketan Mulmuley
- Randomized Algorithms by Rajeev Motwani, Prabhakar Raghavan
- Algorithms on Strings, Trees and Sequences by Dan Gusfield
- Combinatorial Optimization
  by William J. Cook, William H. Cunningham, William R. Pulleyblank, Alexander Schrijver

you should definitely consider the Kleinberg/Tardos book, which is just a great textbook.

Also you should know that on certain topics there are "handbooks" which give an encyclopedic overview over a field (for example the Handbook of Computational Geometry).
 edited by J.R. Sack, J. Urrutia. Notice that these handbooks are pricy. So buying them might help you to spend the 5k.

Comment: You say this is a "random" collection. Do you have particular reasons for recommending those books? What should the OP do with the remaining $4.5k?

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify what your company specializes in, so it's not easy to provide more than general recommendations. On the whole, I think the list you've put together is pretty good, and I wouldn't remove anything from it. Just a couple of additions and comments:

1) Cormen is a standard text. Sedgewick is another standard text. I've always gotten more out of Sedgewick but YMMV. You seem to have the budget. Buy both.

2) I don't have a copy of "The Garbage Collection Handbook" but I do have a well-thumbed copy of Jones&Lin's earlier survey on garbage collection. If you intend to do any sort of automated memory management, you should definitely buy this one.

3) You've also got several useful books on parsing and automata theory, but you're missing the two books (three volumes) which I've found most useful: Sippu & Soisalon-Soisinen's *Parsing Theory*, and Dick Grune's *Parsing Techniques, a Practical Guide*. The first is a great overview of the theory, and the second an exhaustive overview of the practice. (By all means, get the dragon book, too. But I'll bet you'll end up using Grune more.)

4) Every library on data structures requires a copy of Okasaki's "Purely Functional Data Structures". I don't think I've ever read any book this slim with so many interesting ideas.

5) I don't own a copy of Maxime Crochemore's "Algorithms on Strings", but I wish I did. Highly practical, lots of useful ideas.

- Algorithms in C++/Java/C (select one), Third Edition by Robert Sedgewick. Two volumes. Addison-Wesley, 2001.
- The Garbage Collection Handbook by Richard Jones, Antony Hosking and Eliot Moss.
- Parsing Theory, by Seppo Sippu and Eljas Soisalon-Soininen. Two volumes: Vol . 1 Languages and Parsing; Vol. 2 LR(k) and LL(k) Parsing. Springer, 1988.
- Parsing Techniques, A Practical Guide, Second Edition by Dick Grune and Ceriel J.H. Jacobs. Springer, 2008.
- Purely Functional Data Structures by Chris Okasaki. Cambridge, 1998.
- Algorithms on Strings by Maxime Crochemore, Christophe Hancart, Thierry Lecroq. Cambridge, 2007.