# Which textbook can I use after a high school CS course?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, books

I just finished the AP Computer Science course in high school and since my school does not have any further classes, I was thinking about getting a textbook and continuing my study. APCS goes through Big O, Arrays + ArrayLists, Recursion, Linked Lists, a rough overview of some other data structures and some sorting and searching algorithms (all in Java).

I will start Calculus in school next year (if that helps to determine math level).

Since I was thinking about participating in CS tournaments, I thought it would be useful to learn more about algorithms and data structures.

I was looking at two textbooks, *The Algorithm Design Manual* by Steven S Skiena and *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen et. al. I was wondering which one, if any of these, would best fit my situation.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE] and kudos for wanting to learn more! While we have a general dislike of book requests, I think this on might *just* give enough information to allow for somewhat objective answers.

Comment: many refs [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/874/reference-answer-for-textbooks-in-subfields-other-than-algorithms)

Comment: @Raphael Sorry I didn't know the books issue on here. I'll keep it in mind for later!

Comment: @vzn Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Both books you are considering seem like fine choices.  Second hand copies of earlier editions of Cormen et al. are quite cheap, if cost is a concern.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments! I have decided to buy The Algorithm Design Manual because I thought it was more suited to my needs and more appropriate for me in terms of math requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I recommend either [Algorithms](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/book/index.html) by Dasgupta, Papadimitriou, and Vazirani, or *The Algorithm Design Manual* by Skiena.

The Algorithm Design Manual is super-practical and full of excellent pragmatic advice, useful stories, and is well-written and easy to read.  If you want to help get ready for programming contests, I strongly recommend that one.

I think Dasgupta has a better introduction from the perspective of learning the conceptual material, the theory, the proofs underneath the algorithms, etc.  So, if you want to learn the theory, I recommend Dasgupta.

You won't go wrong with either; they are both outstanding.

Personally, I think they are better than Cormen.  I learned from Cormen, and it's a perfectly fine book, but it can be a bit dense in places and a bit challenging to learn from, so it wouldn't be my first recommendation.  Still, it's a reasonable contender and you wouldn't be led astray by it; I just think the others are better.

Comment: Hm, I found Cormen to be quite shallow in some key places, but ymmv.

Answer (score 3):

Cormen et al (CLRS) is aimed towards (undergrad) university students so it may be hard to follow with your current level of mathematics. So, if it has to be one of the two, Skiena may be the more reasonable choice as it is (also) written for professionals.

Other than that, I can recommend Robert Sedgewick's stack. Start with [Introduction to Programming in Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/home/) which takes an interdisciplinary approach (hence requires little formal knowledge) and move on to [Algorithms](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) and [An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/home/). Note that the latter *will* require you dig more into mathematics.

If you are willing do read up on necessary mathematics, almost any introductory undergrad textbook (see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9413/98) for longer lists) should be a good start: pick one you can afford and read the first chapter to see if you like the style. There is no one best book; some work better for some people than others.

Note that these books will give you the university-level computer *science* treatment. If all you want is to be effective in school-level programming tournaments and quickly, you're likely better off with other resources, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: I want to concur with @Raphael: where do you want the book for? Skiena is fun, because it starts with the problem, rather than the data structure offered. But if you want to participate in programming problem solving contests, there should be nice texts that start with problem solving skills (ACM-ICPC ?).