# I need good book about algorithms, which explains recursion, backtracking and depth first recursion for beginners

Tags: algorithms, recursion, python, backtracking, depth-first-search

I'm learning programming, Python 3 in particular, and I have a good book "Beginning Python - From Novice to Professional" by Magnus Lie Hetland, but the book doesn't explain algorithms at all, and I'm having truoble understanding some codes which include recursion since I'm new to 'CS-style' programming, I have moderate to good experience with mathematical code writing and reading/analyzing in MATLAB, which I use mainly for signal-processing and similar techniques of purely mathematical nature, but I'm totally new to the fundamentals of algorithms such as recursion and backtracking and depth-first recursion/search, I have good background in discrete mathematics and set theory, and I'm familiar with the fundamentals os CS like graphs and trees and memory/CPU structures since I'm an electronics engineer, what I really need is a good book(s) about algorithms.

After reading 9 chapters of Hetland's book, nearly half of it, I can say that I have good understanding of the fundamentals of Python 3 and OOP, but the book very often asks the reader to refer to Python's standard library as it doesn't explain many topics, some of which are very necessary, the book also doesn't include any small-projects or programs for practice and skill development, which are really big flaws in my humble opinion!! Although the web is full with video tutorials/courses as well as wikis and other sorts of educational websites, but I think the best way to learn anything is to get a good book describing the material in a structured way, so I got a copy of the infamous book "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein, but after looking at the table of contents and reading the preface and the introduction of t part 1 of the book, I got to think that this book isn't what I'm looking for.

So I very much appreciate any other suggestions of books explaining algorithms for biginners, as well as good books for learning Python 3, Java and C, especially books with many practice/exploration projects and programs.

Thank you!

Comment: There are several standard textbooks on algorithms. They seem to be well-known. Try one of them, according to your mathematical level. You might need a primer on discrete mathematics first.

Comment: Can you give us more specifics about what you *are* looking for?  Just telling us that you want a book on algorithms but not CLRS doesn't leave us much to work with.

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9413/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/44428/755