# Resources on DS and algos

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I am new to this forum as I want to explore data structures and algorithms in depth.

I want to know from experts here what books or other resources would be best for someone like me who can be considered just above a beginner as far as data structures and algorithms is concerned.

Comment: There are several standard textbooks on data structures and algorithms. That would be the obvious approach. Another possibility is looking for online videos, for example on Khan academy.

Comment: Are there some gentle introductory books on the topic? I am not looking for heavyweights like Cormen one. That would be quite difficult to grasp at start.

Comment: Book recommendation questions usually are hard to make work well, as they tend to be opinion-based.  We require you to provide a list of requirements.  I suggest you show what books you've already considered and why you rejected them.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9413/755.  General advice: look at good universities, check out what books they are using for their algorithms and data structures courses, and that will usually give you some idea of which ones are considered good.